# Not able to close the process

Tags: visual-c++

I am not able to close the process nb.exe. I need to close this process but it is not getting closed. During closing I also need to ensure that all the dll are unloaded related to this process. Below is my code.

bool ProcessExit(void)
    {
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

```
HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
{
while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
{
 if (wcsicmp(entry.szExeFile, L"nb.exe") == 0)
{
```

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);

```
ExitProcess(entry.th32ProcessID);

CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
}
}

CloseHandle(snapshot);

return 1;
```

}

Please let me know if you have any inputs.

Comment: Your formatting is messed up: you can edit your question.  What do you mean by "unable"?  Does it give an error, report success but not accomplish, not find the right process in scanning, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mistaken as to what [ExitProcess(value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does.  You are not doing anything to the process running nb.exe, but are exiting the current process with nb's process ID as the exit code.

Comment: Yes you are correct thank you.
I found the issue. However instead of using the ExitProcess I am using TerminateProcess. How can we ensure the Terminate Process saftey from Thread perspective. I found few links on net but all where not sufficient.

Comment: You don't.  Killing another thread does not do any cleanup (destructors, etc.) and might also cause issues that it's not supposed to, such as the infamous stuck IO request that prevents the file from being closed.

Comment: @bally, what is the context?  Is the other process yours, that you can work on the code?  Generally you tell the other process to shut (itself) down using successively more aggressive means and only TerminateProcess as a last resort, because it's already hung.

Comment: @bally, TerminateProcess takes a handle, not an ID, and takes a second argument.  So the code can't be exactly what's shown.  You need to obtain a handle for that processID, and also close it.